# curl set upload chunk size

Tags: bash, curl, file-upload, chunks

I want to upload a big file with `curl`.
For that, I want to split it, without saving it to disk (like with `split`). I tried to use `--continue-at` with `Content-Length`.

```
curl -s \
      --request PATCH \
      --header "Content-Type: application/offset+octet-stream" \
      --header "Content-Length: ${length}" \
      --header "Upload-Offset: ${offset}" \
      --continue-at "${offset}" \
      --upload-file "${file}" \
      "${dest}"
```

But `curl` "overshoots" and ignores `Content-Length`. Is there something like `--stop-at`? Alternatively, I have to use `dd`, if necessary.

**EDIT**
`dd` solution:

```
curl -s \
      --request PATCH \
      --header "Content-Type: application/offset+octet-stream" \
      --header "Content-Length: ${length}" \
      --header "Upload-Offset: ${offset}" \
      --data-binary "@-" \
      "${dest}" < <(dd if=${file} skip=${offset} count=${length} iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes 2>/dev/null)
```

but if possible I would like to use only cURL..

Comment: Just wondering.. have you found any cURL only solution yet? `dd` works good tho.

Comment: Nope, none I know of.